# My listview items are not visible

Tags: php, android

I am an Engineering Student from India.
I am making a project for submission in my college 
I am using webservice in php. Json parsing....
Earlier i was getting correct output , but suddenly i dont know where i made a mistake , i mean when i executed my program next tym i got a list with invisible views.. the in the last line there is a view with details but earlier its was full with all the details.. I am using my localhost as a server.

```
enter code here
```

Code:-

```
public class C_List extends ListActivity {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    public static String selected_college;
    private static final String url = "my localhost ip and db addres.. ";


    public static String Tag_id;
    public static String Tag_college_name;
    public static String Tag_affiliation; 
    public static String Tag_address;
    public static String Tag_contact; 
    public static String Tag_email;
    public static String Tag_website;   
    public static String Tag_longitude; 
    public static String Tag_latitude;  

    public static String id;
    public static String college_name;
    public static String affiliation; 
    public static String address;
    public static String contact; 
    public static String email;
    public static String website;   
    public static String longitude; 
    public static String latitude;  


    JSONArray colleges =null;

    ArrayList<HashMap< String ,String>> collegelist;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);
        collegelist= new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        new Getcollegelist().execute();

    }
    public  class Getcollegelist extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(C_List.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait.....");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            String jsonString=  sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            if (jsonString != null) {
                try{                    
                    JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(jsonString);
                    colleges = jsonObject.getJSONArray("colleges");

                    for (int i = 0; i < colleges.length() ; i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject2 = colleges.getJSONObject(i);
                        Bitmap bmp;
                        id= jsonObject2.getString("c_id");
                        college_name= jsonObject2.getString("college_name");
                        affiliation =jsonObject2.getString("Affiliation");
                        address=jsonObject2.getString("address");
                        contact=jsonObject2.getString("contact_no");
                        email=jsonObject2.getString("email");
                        website=jsonObject2.getString("website");
                        String qrimage=jsonObject2.getString("image");
                        byte[] image=Base64.decode(qrimage.getBytes(), i);
                        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image,0,image.length);

                        contact = jsonObject2.getString("contact_no");

                        HashMap<String, String> collMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        collMap.put(id,id);
                        collMap.put(college_name, college_name);
                        collMap.put(address, address);

                        collegelist.add(collMap);
                    }   
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else
            {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }




        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            pDialog.dismiss();
            ListAdapter adapter= new SimpleAdapter(C_List.this, collegelist , R.layout.text,new String[] {id,college_name, address},
                    new int[] {R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.address} );
            setListAdapter(adapter);

        }}
}

List.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/listbanner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"

        android:divider="#000"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textFilterEnabled="true" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Posting some external links to projects is not the way to ask questions here, post some code, describe your problem and then you'll get help. Consult http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: just post your Activity, listview adapter and xml file you're inflating , then we are able to help you.